# How to insert image as blob in DB2?

Tags: db2, blob

I want to insert a PNG image in DB2. I am able to insert image in my SQL using Load File function. But I don't know how to insert image in DB2 column.

Comment: make a folder and upload .png to here. After upload save .png file path to database

Comment: Yes..Thanks for your immediate reply.I have those images in local drive.I want to use Db2 query to insert my image from my local drive...Please anybody help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139597/inserting-blob-data-in-db2-using-sql-query There are two methods that work mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [sample code](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/nav/4_7_3) provided with DB2, for example [DtLob.java](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/java_jdbc/s-DtLob-java.html)

Comment: I searched a lot.. But i didnt find the exact DB2 query for inserting an image from local drive into db... Please anyone help..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adopt SQL statement to insert images (ex: jpeg, png, gif...etc), you need to convert image to valid string format like this :

hex(base64({images_file}))

Then CAST, and add 'x' before it.

for example:

INSERT INTO table_a (IMG_BLOB) VALUES (CAST(x'FFD8FFE000104A46...') AS BLOB);

You can transcoding {images_file} by following tools:

1. jpeg to base64 : https://onlinejpgtools.com/convert-jpg-to-base64
2. based64 to hex : https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex

IBM DB2 casting reference:

1. Casting between data types : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=types-casting-between-data

Comment: Hi, nice first answer!  It may be more helpful if you include references to the DB2 documentation to back this up.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
db2 sql query to insert image into table
create table table_name(column_name BLOB)        /* BLOP is a data type
insert into table_name(column_name)values(blob('c:\data\winter.jpg'))
```

`c:\data\winter.jpg`   is a path location , `winter.jpg` - image_name

Comment: insert into table_name values (blob('C:\Users\miracle\Pictures\db\CLIPART_OF_10905_SM.jpg')

Comment: This will insert the string "'c:\data\winter.jpg" as a blob into the database. Not the image.